# Send conversion event to Google Ads from NodeJs backend (AWS)

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, gtag.js, google-tag-manager-server-side

I have a website hosted in AWS with a NodeJS backend.

I have Google Ads conversion events being sent from the frontend using gtag.js, but I noticed missing events and a lot of duplication (even if I use transaction IDs with my events)

I had similar issues with Facebook Pixel and was able to resolve the problem by sending simple vanilla http calls from my backend server.

Is it possible to do the same with Google Ads? I have not been able to find any documentation for server side APIs for Javascript.
This [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/upload-offline-conversion) seems promising, but no Javascript SDK exists. That's is why I would like to know what vanilla http calls to make.

I have seen documentation about GTM server side, but it seems I need to host a GTM container (server?) which I would prefer not to have to. Unless I misunderstood what hosting a GTM container means in the context of a AWS cloud solution.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the native, gRPC-based Ads API there's also a REST alternative which can be used if there's no native client library, such as for NodeJS.

The endpoint relevant for your use case is [customers.uploadClickConversions](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v15/customers/uploadClickConversions), which allows you to register a conversion given a specific click ID.

Keep in mind that you'll need to [apply for API access](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token) in order to be able to use the Ads API (aside from accessing test accounts).

Comment: Actual docs link is https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v15/customers/uploadClickConversions

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately these versioned documentation links tend to become stale.